# How to set color background between four points?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to set 4 points and set the color of background between them. How to do that please? How to color the interval for values on x axis?

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem? Any feedback would be polite and appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Check `help rectangle`, `help polygon` and `help coordinates`.

**Code:**

```
### polygons as background

set object 1 polygon from 0,0 to 1,-0.5 to 5,-1 to 7,0 to 4,1 to 3,0.75
set object 1 fc rgb "green" fs solid 1.0 noborder

set object 2 polygon from -4, graph 1 to graph 0, first 0.4 to -7, screen 0
set object 2 fc rgb "yellow" fs solid 1.0 noborder

set object 3 rectangle from first -3, graph 0 to first 1, graph 1
set object 3 fc rgb "red" fs transparent solid 0.5 noborder

plot cos(x)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]